# Is it OK to copy and display Oracle's API Javadoc in my UI

Tags: java, oracle, api, javadoc

I have a user interface that allows users to do String manipulation (among other things).  Behind the scenes, I call static methods (e.g., `java.lang.String.toUpperCase()`, `java.lang.String.toLowerCase()`, `java.lang.String.regionMatches()`, etc.).

The UI is intended to be used by non-programming individuals, and displays things like the parameters that they need to provide to do the String manipulation.  I wanted to provide some help for the users and was wondering if it is legal to copy and paste from the Oracle Javadoc the descriptions of the parameters and include in my help (e.g., regionMatches)

Parameters:

1. toffset - the starting offset of the subregion in this string.
2. other - the string argument.
3. offset - the starting offset of the subregion in the string argument.
4. len - the number of characters to compare.

Thanks for any information on this.

Comment: Did you check the Oracle copyright notices?

Comment: Yes, most of them dealt with the code.  I could not find anything about redisplaying their Javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Oracle's Java SE Documentation Legal Notices page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/legal/cpyr.html):

### License Restrictions Warranty/Consequential Damages Disclaimer

```
This software and related documentation are provided under a license agreement
containing restrictions on use and disclosure and are protected by intellectual
property laws. Except as expressly permitted in your license agreement or 
allowed by law, you may not use, copy, reproduce, translate, broadcast, modify,
license, transmit, distribute, exhibit, perform, publish, or display any part,
in any form, or by any means. Reverse engineering, disassembly, or decompilation
of this software, unless required by law for interoperability, is prohibited.
```

Based on this I'd say that you can't legitimately copy and paste Oracle documentation, but IANAL and you should consult with an attorney to get a real legal opinion.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks.  I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be fine to copy the description from Oracle, in the end just acknowledge them.